# Ajax Getting data from db and store it in array and make a condition in it

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am making a project for my school. I am stuck with this situation:

I am making a function in javascript that runs every 4seconds to get all the queue_id's from my database and store it in an temporary array , and after storing it, every 4seconds, i will get another the-same from my database and check whether it is equal or not, something like if I have a queue_id result from my database of 1,2,3,4 then my next 4secs query is 1,3,4,5 then i would do something. Or maybe if it returns 1,2,3,4,5,6 then i will do the same if it's different, but if it returns again 1,2,3,4,5,6 or the same from the last query I will not do something.

Here is the code:

```
function check_getqueue(clinicID, userID) {
  var tmpCountQ = [];
  var lastCon = [];
  $.ajax({
    url: siteurl+"sec_myclinic/checkingUpdates/"+clinicID+"/"+userID,
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function(data) {
      for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++) {
        tmpCountQ.push(data[i]['queue_id']);
      };
      if(typeof lastCon[0] != "undefined")
      {
        for(j=0;j < tmpCountQ.length;j++)
        {
          if(tmpCountQ[j] != lastCon[j])
          {
            alert("HI");
            lastCon[j] = tmpCountQ[j];
          } 
        }
      }
      else
      {
       lastCon = tmpCountQ;
      }

      console.log(tmpCountQ);
    }
  });
}
```

I tried this code to be run every 4 seconds but it doesn't work like what I want, it doesn't satisfy the condition `if(tmpCountQ[j] != lastCon[j])` that will `alert("HI");` to test it whether it was being satisfied. Please help me, here is the 1st and the 2nd returned data from this code:

[image]

It must give me an alert of HI because the 1st JSON gives me 2,3 and the next is 1,3 . Please help.. thanks

Please help, anybody here from Stackoverflow - I need help

Answer (score 0):

Your reassigning your array to be empty, so your check to  initialArray[0]===undefined will cause it to skip the comparison, but your array is amply anyway

Move the declaration 
     var lastCon = [];
outside of
The function, this will cause it to be global which may not be desirable, but it will fix the code.

Comment: can you please edit my code to satisfy what i want please.

Comment: Change your code so that instead of comparing the array lengths; change them to strings and compare.

Comment: there sir sorry,, i forgot to check my code in question. i was posting a wrong code. i updated my question.

Comment: hello sir? what is arry1.join()==arry2.join()

Comment: i think your reassigning lastCon as an empty array again, so that lastCon[0]== undefined and the comparison never runs